# jquery .one("click", function())

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to get the .one from jquery to only allow the color to be changed once even after clicking again, and i cant figure out why it wont work. 
This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id= "container">
      <div class="grid">
        <div id= "box1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
#box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and finally, this is my JS:

```
function changeColor() {
    var box = document.getElementById("box1");
    $("box1").one("click", function() {
        box.style = "background: " + genColor();
    });
};


window.onload = changeColor

function genColor() {
    var arr = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'teal'];
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
    return arr[x]
}
```

I am trying to get my changeColor function to work only once. and if i click it again nothing happens.

Comment: Typo: `$("box1")` should be `$("#box1")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.one` should be `.on` then attach the event to the button on document ready so you could trigger the onclick multiple times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box1");
  $("#box1").on("click", function() {
    box.style = "background: " + genColor();
  });
});

function genColor() {
  var arr = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'teal'];
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
  return arr[x]
}
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  right: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleSheets/main.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div id="box1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeColor() {
    $("#box1").one("click", function() {
        //box.style = "background: " + genColor();
        $(this).css("background", genColor());
    });
};


window.onload = changeColor

function genColor() {
    var arr = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'teal'];
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length - 1);
    return arr[x]
}
```

```css
#box1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 200px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id= "container">
      <div class="grid">
        <div id= "box1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to do 2 changes in your code:**

**1:**
Change `window.onload = changeColor` this line to `window.onload = changeColor();`

*(Here you have missed the function parentheses `();`)*

**2:**
Change  `$("box1").one("click", function()` this line to  `$("#box1").on("click", function()`

(*Here you have missed the jQuery id selector* `#` and `.on`)

**Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onav9exj/1/)**